# I have the following string '3,45,543,6,89'. Need output like table thorugh function. Pl help me get output through postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.SplitToTable(
iv_datalist  varchar,iv_Separator varchar)
    RETURNS TABLE(out_param varchar)  
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$
BEGIN

RETURN query select (select regexp_split_to_table(iv_datalist, iv_Separator) as out_param );

END
$BODY$;
```

When I run

```
select * from splitToTable('3,34,4,545,35,3',',');
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type text does not match expected type character varying in column 1.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function splittotable1(character varying,character varying) line 4 at RETURN QUERY
SQL state: 42804
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to declare the function as `RETURNS text` rather than `RETURNS varchar`. Use `text` everywhere, as that is the preferred string type in PostgreSQL. That way, you have no problems with type conversions.

The function could be written simpler as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.SplitToTable(
   iv_datalist text,
   iv_Separator text
) RETURNS TABLE(out_param text)  
    LANGUAGE sql
    IMMUTABLE
AS
$BODY$SELECT * FROM regexp_split_to_table(iv_datalist, iv_Separator);$BODY$;
```

Essentially, the function is useless; you could just use `regexp_split_to_table` directly.